# how to use nfs with magento webserver in a cluster environment

Tags: magento, debian, cluster-computing, nfs

i'm having a little hard time makeing a magento EE installation faster. The environmen is built on CloudStack with lodabalance, 2 x nginx webserver with php onboard, 1 x vm with a nfs share exported, 2 x percona cluster, 1 x redis / memcache

now, i have placed the magento folder directly on the nfs exported share, i mean the complete magento folder and webservers have the share mounted and serving all the content from that folder.

websites are slow, not very slow but slow. my question is:

in a clustered environment with many webservers and a nfs share, is technically correct to place all the magento folder on it, or it's better to export only the /media folder on the nfs and the somehow (cron + rsync?) sync contents between nodes?

thank you

btw, website are www.mykidz.it, www.sanecovit.it

Answer (score 0):

You should share only two magento's directories: `media` and `var`

Sharing full magento source code is slow with NFS.

Comment: Ok and what about replicanting the other left folders and files across webnodes? Rsync? Lsyncd? Thx

Comment: You don't need to replicate other folders, just put its copy to each webnode. If you update source code frequency, I suggest you to use Capistrano (Webistrano) or something else do deploy code to multi-servers at the same time.